# Javascript or jQuery fetch a Processingjs variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing

Is it possible to pass a variable *from* [processingjs](http://processingjs.org) to Javascript / jQuery for use in AJAX send to server

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. There are many ways, one of the ways is to attach the variable you wish to pass around to the `window` object. It's not the *only* solution and definitely not the most *elegant* solution, but, it works.

So something like this:

```
// processingjs code...
window.varIWantToPassAround = "whatever"; 

// jQuery code... 
// as long as you don't redefine the variable "varIWantToPassAround", you can reference it without referencing the window object. IE "window.varIWantToPassAround"
// but I like to be explicit so when I read my code 3 months later and go "where did *that* come from, I can see it is attached to the window object.
$("#unicorn_powerd_div").someFunctionThatGrowsMagicUnicorns(window.varIWantToPassAround);
```